# loop through object and get properties

Tags: c#, object

i have a method that returns a list of operating system properties. Id like to loop through the properties and do some processing on each one.All properties are strings

How do i loop through the object

**C#**

```
// test1 and test2 so you can see a simple example of the properties - although these are not part of the question
String test1 = OS_Result.OSResultStruct.OSBuild;
String test2 = OS_Result.OSResultStruct.OSMajor;

// here is what i would like to be able to do
foreach (string s in OS_Result.OSResultStruct)
{
    // get the string and do some work....
    string test = s;
    //......

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it with *reflection*:

```
// Obtain a list of properties of string type
var stringProps = OS_Result
    .OSResultStruct
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));
foreach (var prop in stringProps) {
    // Use the PropertyInfo object to extract the corresponding value
    // from the OS_Result.OSResultStruct object
    string val = (string)prop.GetValue(OS_Result.OSResultStruct);
    ...
}
```

[EDIT by [Matthew Watson]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson)

I've taken the liberty of adding a further code sample, based on the code above.

You could generalise the solution by writing a method that will return an `IEnumerable<string>` for any object type:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> StringProperties(object obj)
{
    return from p in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
            where p.PropertyType == typeof(string)
            select new KeyValuePair<string,string>(p.Name, (string)p.GetValue(obj));
}
```

And you can generalise it even further with generics:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,T>> PropertiesOfType<T>(object obj)
{
    return from p in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
            where p.PropertyType == typeof(T)
            select new KeyValuePair<string,T>(p.Name, (T)p.GetValue(obj));
}
```

Using this second form, to iterate over all the string properties of an object you could do:

```
foreach (var property in PropertiesOfType<string>(myObject)) {
    var name = property.Key;
    var val = property.Value;
    ...
}
```

Comment: on the line "string val = (string)prop.GetValue(OS_Result.OSResultStruct);" - i get the Error No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @user1438082 It looks like you're using .NET 4.0 or earlier; try the older version `GetValue(OS_Result.OSResultStruct, null)` then.

Comment: hi, nearly - its returning the property but i am looking for the name e.g OSBuild and OSMajor for the example in the question.

Comment: @user1438082 That would be `prop.Name` then.

Comment: Nice snippet. I'll be grabbing a copy of that, then. *hoick*  ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks for the edit! I changed the output to `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,T>>` to give users of your methods access to property names, in addition to the property values.

Comment: That's even better! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Reflection to loop the `GetProperties` Resullt:

```
OS_Result.OSResultStruct.GetType().GetProperties()
```