# Using LINQ on local squence to group by parent and child properties

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Continuing from the Q&As dealing with looping through an object's properties ([Using LINQ to loop through inner class properties in outer class collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109004/using-linq-to-loop-through-inner-class-properties-in-outer-class-collection/)), is it possible to populate a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<ComplexKey,IEnumerable<double>> answer;
```

For example,

- answer[1,1,1,"MeasurementA"] = {2.0, 2.1}
- answer[1,1,1,"MeasurementB"] = {3.0, 3.1}
- answer[1,1,1,"MeasurementC"] = {4.0, 4.1}
- answer[1,1,2,"MeasurementA"] = {5.0, 5.1}

Given the structure:

```
class MainClass {
  List<Class1> list
}

class Class1 {
  // a number of fields including...
  int PropertyA { get; set; }
  int PropertyB { get; set; }
  Dictionary<int, Class2> dict { get; set; }
}

class Class2 {
  // a number of fields all of type double...
  double MeasurementA { get; set; }
  double MeasurementB { get; set; }
  double MeasurementC { get; set; }
}

struct ComplexKey {
  public int class1PropA;
  public int class1PropB;
  public int class1DictKey;  
  public string class2PropName;
}
```

Given data:

```
MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
mainClass.list = new List<Class1>() {
  new Class1() {
    PropertyA = 1,
    PropertyB = 1, 
    dict = new Dictionary<int,Class2>() {
      { 1, new Class2() { MeasurementA = 2.0, MeasurementB = 3.0, MeasurementC = 4.0 }},
      { 2, new Class2() { MeasurementA = 5.0, MeasurementB = 6.0, MeasurementC = 7.0 }}
    }
  },
  new Class1() { 
    PropertyA = 1,
    PropertyB = 1, 
    dict = new Dictionary<int,Class2>() {
      { 1, new Class2() { MeasurementA = 2.1, MeasurementB = 3.1, MeasurementC = 4.1 }},
      { 2, new Class2() { MeasurementA = 5.1, MeasurementB = 6.1, MeasurementC = 7.1 }}
    }
  }
};
```

Noting in this example, Class1.PropertyA and Class1.PropertyB are consistently set to "1" for brevity.  (This is not the case in the real world data set).

I believe populating the Dictionary "answer" would require, grouping the mainclass.list by PropertyA, PropertyB, and dict.Key before accessing the properties and values within dict.Values (i.e. instances of Class2).

I thought LINQ was the answer but have been stuck for many weeks.  Any direction would be appreciated.

Thanks & regards
Shannon

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far so that some one can help you.

Comment: In the related query @KonradKokosa provided the partial answer:  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21109689/3176705).  To include the outer iteration variable reference I am trying comprehension syntax:

Comment: var flds = from p in typeof(Class2).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)    from c1 in mainClass.list   from d in c1.dict    select new    {      class1PropA = c1.PropertyA,      class1PropB = c1.PropertyB,      class1DictKey = d.Key,      class2PropName = p.Name,      val = p.GetValue(d, null)    };

Comment: Apologies.  I am having trouble posting the code as CODE.

Comment: What's is an output? I mean the collection  of doubles (as value in dictionary). I completetly can't get it.

Comment: @pwas You are correct, the output is a dictionary with a collection of doubles as the value.  The real-life example will create an instance of another Class which will calculate a distribution from the collection of doubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question you linked, it seems you're looking for something like this:

```
var answer = 
 typeof(Class2).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
               .SelectMany(pi => mainClass.list.SelectMany(c1 => 
                    c1.dict.Select(i => new {
                                                c1.PropertyA, 
                                                c1.PropertyB, 
                                                i.Key,
                                                i.Value}))
                            .Select(p => new {
                                                Key = new ComplexKey {
                                                    class1PropA = p.PropertyA,
                                                    class1PropB = p.PropertyB,
                                                    class1DictKey = p.Key,
                                                    class2PropName = pi.Name},
                                                Value = (double)pi.GetValue(p.Value)}))
                .GroupBy(grp => grp.Key)
                .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Select(x => x.Value));
```

`answer` is now

[image]

**Note**: If you use a custom type (like `ComplexKey`) as key in a `Dictionary`, you should implement a proper `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method, since these methods are used to distinguish the keys inside the `Dictionary`.

Comment: This is brilliant!  The picture looks like it is a screenshot from LinqPad.  Based on the LinqPad "Custom methods and types" sample, I can see the classes & struct can be added outside the Main() block.  The mainclass instanciated inside the Main() block along with your LINQ query.  However, on the line `Value = (double)pi.GetValue(p.Value)}))` LinqPad returns the error `No overload for method 'GetValue' takes '1' arguments`.  Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Changing the line `Value = (double)pi.GetValue(p.Value)` to `Value = (double)pi.GetValue(p.Value,null)`, results "Query successful".  However, no results are displayed using Rich Text or Data Grids formats.  Any ideas?

Comment: Found it!  `answer.Dump();`