# Using LINQ to loop through inner class properties in outer class collection and group by outer class properties

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Leveraging off the Q&As dealing with looping through an object's properties ([Loop Through An Objects Properties In C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586123/loop-through-object-and-get-properties) and [Using LINQ to loop through inner class properties in outer class collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109004/using-linq-to-loop-through-inner-class-properties-in-outer-class-collection)), where you have:

- a collection of Class1 objects (i.e. listObj1)
- each Class1 contains properties and a collection of Class2 objects (i.e. dictObj2)

How would you:

- Efficiently determine the properties of the inner class (Class2)
- loop through the the properties of the inner class (Class2)
- loop through the collection of Class1 objects (listObj1) selecting all instances of the the Class2 property
- output the collection of Class2 property (e.g. the first iteration would return a collection of MeasurementA, one from each Class1 object).
- and **group the collection by Class1.PropertyA and Class1.PropertyB**

Please find below a rough map of the classes involved.

I have been trying to use a LINQ query without success. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21109689/3176705) provided by Konrad Kokosa is most of the way there.  Any ideas or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
class MainClass {
  List<Class1> listObj1
}

class Class1 {
  // a number of fields including...
  int PropertyA { get; set; }
  int PropertyB { get; set; }
  Dictionary<int, Class2> dictObj2 { get; set; }
}

class Class2 {
  // a number of fields all of type double...
  double MeasurementA { get; set; }
  double MeasurementB { get; set; }
  double MeasurementC { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Loop:**

```
foreach(var cls1 in listObj1)
{
    int tempA = cls1.PropertyA;
    foreach(var cls2 in cls1.dictObj2)
    {
         double tempB = cls2.MeasurementB;
    }
}
```

**Filtered/Efficient Loop:**

```
foreach(var cls1 in listObj1.Where(c1=> c1.PropertyA > 5 && c1.PropertyB > 3))
{
    int tempA = cls1.PropertyA;
    foreach(var cls2 in cls1.dictObj2.Where(c2=> c2.MeasurementA >= 10))
    {
         double tempB = cls2.MeasurementB;
    }
}
```