# Is it possible to bind properties of a model class to a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, properties, combobox

*(note: I'm tagging it `winforms` yet I think it does apply to WPF as well)*

I have a ComboBox and a model class (let's say Person). Person contains multiple public properties (Name, Age, Sex, Adress and so on).

Is there a (standard) way to bind my ComboBox's data source to these properties, so the ComboBox shows "Name", "Age", "Sex" and "Adress" as its list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091414/winforms-combobox-with-multiple-columns-c

Comment: Do you want to display property names in combo box?

Comment: Yeah, that's my objective. @Sajeetharan: unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<PropertyInfo> DataSource = new BindingList<PropertyInfo>();

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingList<PropertyInfo>(typeof(Person).GetProperties());
        // if want to specify only name (not type-name/property-name tuple)
        comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }
}
```

Your class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint Age { get; set; }
    public bool Sex { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I knew it would have to deal with reflection sadly... Yet it's what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get property names, use reflection:

```
var propertyNames = person
    .GetType() // or typeof(Person)
    .GetProperties()
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .ToArray();
```

(since the result will be the same for all `Person` instances, I'd cache it, e.g. in static variable).

To display properties in combo box, use `DataSource` (WinForms):

```
comboBox.DataSource = propertyNames;
```

or `ItemsSource` (WPF):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyNames}"/>
```

(assuming, that current data context contains public property `PropertyNames`).

Answer (score 0):

In WPF:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Address { get;set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", Name, Age, Sex, Address);
    }
}

public class PersonViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        PersonList = (from p in DataContext.Person
                      select new Person
                      {
                          Name = p.Name,
                          Age = p.Age,
                          Sex = p.Sex,
                          Address = p.Address
                      }).ToList();
    }

    public List<Person> PersonList { get; set; }
    public Person SelectedPerson { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"/>
```

Comment: I don't need to display the content of the properties, but their names.

Comment: Sorry... Check this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586123/loop-through-object-and-get-properties