# Convert an object to string array at runtime

Tags: c#, casting

I have a line in my code:

```
var objects = ExternalApiGetObjects(....);
```

At develop time I only know that `ExternalApiGetObjects` returns an `Object` instance. In fact, I'm sure that `objects` variable is an array of some type.
I want to pass `objects` variable to `String.Join` method, but in runtime I got an exception similar to this: "Object of type 'System.Int32[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.String[]'."

In most cases, an `objects` will not be a string array. It could be an int array, or even an array of some user's type. I just know that objects is an array and I want to invoke `ToString()` on each item of that array to create a new one with type of `string[]`.

How can I convert my `objects` to `string[]`?

Comment: Cast it? `var newObjects = objects as string[];` If it is actually that type then it you are done. If not `newObjects` will be null.

Comment: Just loop through it? `var objects = apiResult; foreach (var object in objects) {...}`

Comment: In most cases, an `objects` will not be a string array. It could be an int array, or even an array of some user's type. I just know that `objects` is an array and I  want to invoke `ToString()` on each item of that array to create a new one with type of `string[]`

Comment: Have you seen this question? Does it help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586123/loop-through-object-and-get-properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **OP:** It could be an
>   int array, or even an array of some user's type. I just know that
>   objects is an array and I want to invoke ToString() on each item of
>   that array to create a new one with type of string[]

You can cast it to [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), then using [`Cast<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) convert elements to object and then select elements. For example:

```
object o = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var array = (o as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I wish I was  allowed to use a comment to say "very neat"

Comment: @EvanL Read the quote.

Comment: I stand corrected, ran a few samples of this myself.  Forgot how magical the `Cast<T>()` method could be!